# Asus Q301L - No Sound in Ubuntu 13.04 x86

Tags: 13.04, sound, asus

I just bought a nifty laptop and immediate ditched Windows 8 in favor of Ubuntu. Everthing works perfectly, even the touchscreen. All with the exception of sound. Ubuntu shows my sound as detected but I hear nothing. I can plug external speakers into the headphone jacks and I hear sound just fine. Unplug, nothing. I'm a complete n00b with Ubuntu. :(

I followed some directions on other forums for somewhat similar Asus laptops with SonicMaster sound. They had be rip out Pulse Audio and that didn't help. I removed and reinstalled Alsa and Pulse Audio and the sound indicator application (for the sound icon at the top of the screen). Now the test buttons in the Sound application do not seem to work, but I do get sound through external speakers. Just not the internal speakers. Lost! Help! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your audio might be set to returns sound only to your headphone jacks.
Simply edit this setting:

- open **pulse**
  [image]
- in 3<sup>rd</sup> tab, replace "headphone" by **"speakers"**
  [image]

Comment: I looked and I only have the HDMI port audio (which I don't use) and something called Built-In Analog Stereo (which is my onboard sound) but it doesn't have a drop-down to pick from. What does that mean? :o

Comment: I'm looking for a way to attach pictures but I do not see one yet. :( Will post as soon as I can.

Comment: I tried but the message board will not let me. It says I need 10 reputation points to post an image. I can email them or something, I guess. This is my first time to post and ask for help. How do I get rep points? Can you add rep points to me somehow or do I have to post on other people's threads to go up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HDMI port audio, then set Pulse like this:

- open **pulse**

[image]

- in 3<sup>rd</sup> tab, keep **HDMI display port**

[image]

- in last tab **configuration**, make sure that you are using your **HDMI output**

[image]